# PHP: MongoDB projection on embedded document array with positional operator

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, embedded-documents

I want to retrieve a specific array from embedded document on matching base but either the output is displaying all arrays in that document not a specific one or displaying just the first array....
this is my code please have a look and answer this according to PHP.

```
$dept->findOne(['$and' => [
    ['_id' => 'd004'],
    ['dept_employees.from_date' => '1986-12-01'],
    ['dept_employees.to_date' => '9999-01-01']
                         ]
    ],
    ['projection' => ['dept_employees.$' => 1] ]);
```

this is the output

> ```
> MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument::__set_state(array(
>    '_id' => 'd004',
>    'dept_employees' => 
>   MongoDB\Model\BSONArray::__set_state(array(
>      0 => 
>     MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument::__set_state(array(
>        'emp_id' => '10003',
>        'from_date' => '1995-12-03',
>        'to_date' => '9999-01-01',
>     )),
>   )),
> ))
> ```

the document is like this have 247 sub-arrays

> ```
> MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument::__set_state(array(
>    '_id' => 'd004',
>    'dept_employees' => 
>   MongoDB\Model\BSONArray::__set_state(array(
>      0 => 
>     MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument::__set_state(array(
>        'emp_id' => '10003',
>        'from_date' => '1995-12-03',
>        'to_date' => '9999-01-01',
>     )),
>      1 => 
>     MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument::__set_state(array(
>        'emp_id' => '10004',
>        'from_date' => '1986-12-01',
>        'to_date' => '9999-01-01',
>     )),
>      2 => 
>     MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument::__set_state(array(
>        'emp_id' => '10010',
>        'from_date' => '1996-11-24',
>        'to_date' => '2000-06-26',
>     )),
> ```

and i want only this

> ```
> MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument::__set_state(array(
>    '_id' => 'd004',
>    'dept_employees' => 
>   MongoDB\Model\BSONArray::__set_state(array(
>
>      1 => 
>     MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument::__set_state(array(
>        'emp_id' => '10004',
>        'from_date' => '1986-12-01',
>        'to_date' => '9999-01-01',
>     )),
> ```

Dates are here only as strings, i am  just matching strings. 
The shell is also displaying same results:

```
db.departments.find( {"dept_employees.from_date": '1986-12-01',    
"dept_employees.to_date": '9999-01-01'}, {"dept_employees.$":1} ).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "d004",
        "dept_employees" : [
                {
                        "emp_id" : "10003",
                        "from_date" : "1995-12-03",
                        "to_date" : "9999-01-01"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Use elemMatch for mulitple query criteria. Something like `db.departments.find( { dept_employees: { $elemMatch: {
                                            from_date:  '1986-12-01',
                                            to_date: '9999-01-01'
                                          } } },
                  { "dept_employees.$": 1 } )`. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-for-an-array-element-that-meets-multiple-criteria

Comment: @Veeram thankx... your suggestion is working in mongo shell but not in PHP. `$dept->find( [ 'dept_employees' => [ '$elemMatch' =>
    [ 'from_date' => '1986-12-01', 'to_date' => '9999-01-01' ]
                            ] ], [ "dept_employees.$" => 1 ] ); ` displays only this **MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::__set_state(array())**

Comment: Try `findOne` or you have to iterate the results when using `find`

Comment: @Veeram i tried findOne it displays all arays but in mongo shell it works right. i just pasted your first comment in mongo shell and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

According to MongoDB documentation :

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  from the
>   query results to contain only the first element matching the query
>   document.

and :

> See the aggregation operator $filter to return an array with only those 
>   elements that match the specified condition.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter

Also, not exactly sure in your case, but if you are looking to match date ranges, maybe using '$gt' and '$lt' can help.

Comment: `db.departments.aggregate([   {    $project: {   dept_employees: {   $filter: {   input: "$dept_employees",             as: "dept_employee",  cond: {  "$$dept_employee.emp_id": 10010 }     }         }      }   } ])` showing error

Comment: **"errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$$dept_employee.emp_id'"**